# How to Automatically "Reset to Quick Styles from XYZ Template" in Word 2007?

Tags: automation, ms-office, office-2007, word-2007

In Word 2007, a user may update the applied styles by selecting the "Reset to Quick Styles from XYZ Template" in the Change Styles menu option.

[image: Reset to Quick Styles from XYZ Template]

Does anyone know of a way to automate this? I tried adding a macro to the Document_Open() method in the VBA for the Template project, but it errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you record a macro of the 'Reset to Quick Styles from *xxx* Template', Word generates the VBA code:

```
WordBasic.ApplyQFSetTemplate
```

I couldn't get this command to work either, nor find anything Word VBA docs about it. Instead, use the following command when the correct template is attached:

```
ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles
```

That one does work consistently!